# Can't reference non-static object from field initializer

Tags: c#

I wrote this code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    ThreadStart ts = new ThreadStart(fun1);
    public Thread t1 = new Thread(ts);
    public void fun1()
    {
        DA da = new DA();

        string q = "select * from G5_table order by State";

        DataTable dt = da.Select(q);
        foreach (DataRow item in dt.Rows)
        {
            richtxtboxEN.Text = item["Word_en"].ToString();
            mode = 1;
            richtxtboxEN.TextChanged += new EventHandler(richtxtboxEN_TextChanged);
        }
    }
    private void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {     
        t1.Start();
    }
}
```

but i have a error 
field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property 'G5.Form1.fun1()

Comment: What is the connection between that error and the title?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot access a non-static method within a field initializer like you are doing here:

```
ThreadStart ts = new ThreadStart(fun1);
```

You will need to define a constructor instead, like this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        ts = new ThreadStart(fun1);
        t1 = new Thread(ts);
    }

    ThreadStart ts;
    public Thread t1;
```

Comment: What was wrong with my answer, that was posted 5 minutes before? You are saying the exact same thing.

Answer (score 2):

Change your `Form1_Shown` to this:

```
private void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{   
    t1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(fun1));  
    t1.Start();
}
```

then change `t1` to this:

```
public Thread t1;
```

and remove `ts` from your class completely.

The error, is that you cant reference non-static things in field initializers. And that even includes other class-level fields.

And for clarification, a field initializer is this:

```
public Thread t1 = new Thread(ts);
```

Since `Thread t1` is not a property, and is defined at class-level (outside of a method), it is a field, and it is being initialized right there in the declaration. It is referencing `ts` which is a non-static field, and you can not do this.